# selection of elements in Jquery drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a form to enter personal details. I use Jquery drop down to add the country and state.
when i select the country in the drop down the state drop down appears where i can select the state.

My problem is - during update of the personal details i populate the same form with data i get from the database. I am not able to select the same country which i receive from the databse in the drop down.

This is the drop down code

```
<select onchange="print_state('state',this.selectedIndex);" id="country"               name="country">


</select>

<select name ="<spring:message code="state" id = "state"></select>
<script language="javascript">print_country("country");</script>


  this is how the js file looks..                                     
  var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria"...}
  var s_a = new Array();
  s_a[0]="";
  s_a[1]="Badakhshan|Badghis|Baghlan|Balkh|Bamian|...}
```

Comment: how do you receive from database? ajax?

Comment: No. I have an object which is set in the request scope.

Comment: when you populate the same form for updating, do you have the `selectedIndex` which user previously chose?

Comment: no..i just have a string

Comment: this is how the js file looks..                                     var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria"...}var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0]="";
s_a[1]="Badakhshan|Badghis|Baghlan|Balkh|Bamian|...}

Comment: I realize that the indexes should also be stored.....

Comment: am i right..? should the indexes be stored..

Comment: you have to figure out where do you store the `selectedIndex`, also describe your scenario whether the update window is opened after page refreshing or not